# How Do I Use A Table As A Footer?

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm trying to use a table that is currently at the bottom of my page as a footer which needs to be at the bottom of the page and doesn't move as your scroll up and down the page.

Here is what I have so far:

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="footer">Weather&nbsp;Station&nbsp;Davis Vantage Pro2</td>
    <td class="footer">Page&nbsp;Updated&nbsp;14:46 01 November 2016</td>
    <td class="footer">Powered&nbsp;By&nbsp;<a href="http://sandaysoft.com/products/cumulus" target="_blank">Cumulus</a>&nbsp;v3.0.0&nbsp;(3041)</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.footer {
  font-size: 10pt;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  color: #000000;
  padding: 3px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

I have tried using tbody tags but nothing changed.

Thanks,

William

Comment: That does not look like tabular data. Don't use tables for layout. We've had CSS for about two decades now.

Comment: how do you use a table as a footer? You don't... that's how

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tables are not recommended for layouting. Use the proper tags for the different page sections. In this case `<footer>` would be appropriate. Just use `div` tags for your footer data and set `display: inline-block;` for them to appear next to each other.

Also you can use `position: fixed;` in combination with `bottom: 0;` to make your footer stick to the bottom. I rebuild your code for your reference:

```css
footer > div {
  font-size: 10pt;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  color: #000000;
  padding: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}
footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div>Weather&nbsp;Station&nbsp;Davis Vantage Pro2</div>
  <div>Page&nbsp;Updated&nbsp;14:46 01 November 2016</div>
  <div>Powered&nbsp;By&nbsp;<a href="http://sandaysoft.com/products/cumulus" target="_blank">Cumulus</a>&nbsp;v3.0.0&nbsp;(3041)</div>
</footer>
```

See more about the [`<footer>` tag on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/footer).

Comment: Thanks, that's worked, but the only thing I need is the layout that they were in before as shown in the header on this page: http://newton-poppleford-weather.co.uk/index.htm As you can see the footer is aligned differently to that.

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help. I appreciate an upvote/accept ;) You are already using the `<footer>` element on that page, thats good ;) Just apply the position I mentioned above and you are good to go.

Comment: It's all done, but I presume I need to reapply the font-size etc. is that footer actually on the bottom of the page or not now?